# Add a Script button in W3 Total Cache plugin not working due to conflicting jQuery version

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, plugin-w3-total-cache

While trying to fix the Render-Blocking issue on my website, I ran into a problem with the W3 Total Cache plugin on its Minify settings page.

The two buttons to add JS (Add a script) and CSS (Add a style sheet) are not working, nothing happens after clicking them.

The cause of the issue can be seen in the browser console error message (WP uses jQuery `1.12.4`, W3TC requires jQuery `<1.9`)

[Related question jQuery(...).live is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function)

```
options.js?ver=0.9.6:324 
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (options.js?ver=0.9.6:324)
    at i (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,utils&ver=4.8.5:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,utils&ver=4.8.5:2)
    at Function.ready (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,utils&ver=4.8.5:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,utils&ver=4.8.5:2)
```

`options.js` is the file causing the issue on lines like this (`jQuery(...).live` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.9):

```
jQuery('#pgcache__reject__logged_roles').live('click', function(){
        w3tc_input_enable('#pgcache_reject_roles input[type=checkbox]', jQuery('#pgcache__reject__logged_roles:checked').size());
    });
```

What would be the most acceptable and cleanest way to resolve the issue:

- Is there an updated W3TC plugin?
- Is there a clean way to make W3TC use different jQuery version than WP?
- Using a jQuery plugin like jQuery Migrate?
- Manually changing the affected lines?

[image: JS minify settings]

Comment: The object reference for the jQuery included with WordPress is `jQuery`, not the default `$`.

Comment: The code example in the question already uses `jQuery`

Comment: Your edit has added new information, I pointed that out as I noticed you were loading your own version of jQuery, which you’ve now removed.

Comment: You're right, but that's the jQuery included with the theme. After realizing that the error has to do with WP-Admin (the theme doesn't get loaded), I deleted the code segment. The `jQuery 1.12.4` gets loaded as part of WP-Includes (`/www/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js`)

Answer (score 0):

WP Admin normally loads the migrate script automatically. Apparently your theme dequeued/deregistered that script (too).

The upcoming release fixes issues with calls to the deprecated live() function in cases like yours where the migrate script doesn't work or is not loaded.